# Issue creating Likert-scale plots in r

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to plot data from a study that used a Likert-scale measurement. I am using the ['Likert' package](https://github.com/jbryer/likert). The problem I have occurs when I try to group the data in the plot. For illustratation, I will demonstrate using a dataset that is used in many of the online demos such as
[this one](http://jason.bryer.org/likert/)

When I run the code, I want/expect a graph that looks like this (notice that the bar plots are organised in a nice ordered sequence from 'strongly disagree' to 'strongly agree'):
[image]

When I run the following code, I get a graph where the order is confused; mainly 'agree' and 'strongly agree' are swapped around. Can anyone shed some light as to why this might be happening and how I can fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
require(likert)
library(plyr)

##### import built-in data
data(pisaitems)

# extract data for analysis
items24 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) == 'ST24Q']

# rename cols
items24 <- rename(items24, c(
  ST24Q01="I read only if I have to.",
  ST24Q02="Reading is one of my favorite hobbies.",
  ST24Q03="I like talking about books with other people.",
  ST24Q04="I find it hard to finish books.",
  ST24Q05="I feel happy if I receive a book as a present.",
  ST24Q06="For me, reading is a waste of time.",
  ST24Q07="I enjoy going to a bookstore or a library.",
  ST24Q08="I read only to get information that I need.",
  ST24Q09="I cannot sit still and read for more than a few minutes.",
  ST24Q10="I like to express my opinions about books I have read.",
  ST24Q11="I like to exchange books with my friends."))

# capture Likert data by group
l24g <- likert(items24[,1:11], grouping=pisaitems$CNT)

# plot
plot(l24g)
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bug. See [here](https://github.com/jbryer/likert/issues/63).

Comment: perfect - thanks worked a treat!